# Fetch data from any url in iPhone hides statusBar from child View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, feed, nsurl

I am trying to implement a functionality like below images in iPhone.
**my requirement is,** if user enters any website URL link or youtube video URL link in `textview`, then I want to get(fetch) that URL title, description, base URL from link, and default image. Then I'll display it as below images. I am successful with below code to fetch any url title.. but am unable to grab description, base URL from link,and default image.

```
NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:_textView.text encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        if(html)
        {
            NSLog(@"HTML %@", html);
            NSRange r = [html rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                NSRange r1 = [html rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
                if (r1.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    if (r1.location > r.location)
                    {
                        NSString *title = [html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(r), r1.location - NSMaxRange(r))];
                        NSLog(@"title %@", title);
                        lable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                        lable.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 280, 30);
                        lable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                        lable.text = title;
                        lable.numberOfLines=2;
                        lable.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
                        lable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:14];
                        [youCell addSubview:lable];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

if any one having any ideas plz share with me...thank in advance...

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: please tell me how can i do this...

Comment: You are not going to be able to parse HTML with mere `rangeOfString:` calls. You need regular expressions at the very least.

Comment: ok but i don't have idea about this can u plz suggest any link or piece of code..

Answer (score 0):

You Need To cover inputString into the URL.

```
  NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *inputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_textView.text];
        NSString *pageSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:inputURL
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];
        if(pageSource)
        {
            NSRange startTitle = [pageSource rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
            if (startTitle.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                NSRange endTitle = [pageSource rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
                if (endTitle.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    if (endTitle.location > startTitle.location)
                    {
                        NSString *pageTitle = [pageSource substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(startTitle), endTitle.location - NSMaxRange(startTitle))];
                        NSLog(@"Title of Page := %@", pageTitle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: am grabing title with my code but right now i need to grab url description and default image...